# unlock package Error

Tags: salesforcedx

I am trying to complete unlock package badge.. I have alot of issues completing this challenge...at the moment i am at this stage (see image below)
[image]

as i try to insert higlighted command mentioned in number 4 in the image. I get the following error "ERROR running force:package:version:create:  The package dreamhouse isn’t defined in the sfdx-project.json file. Add it to the packageDirectories section and add the alias to packageAliases with its 0Ho ID."
(see image below)
[image]

The package is clearly defined in SFDX Json file and the package alias is also added in json file.. I did this with the help of a gentleman throug this amazing platform..Please advise me how i can resolve it as i really wanna finish this challenge. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple, but easy mistake to make...

The package name in `packageDirectories` is case-sensitive. You currently have it as `"Dreamhouse"`, whereas your package alias is defined as `"dreamhouse"`. The name used in the command-line command also needs to match. The command you used to build the package was:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p dreamhouse -d force-app -k test1234 --wait 10 -v DevHub
```

If you change them to match, then it ought to work.

Comment: i changed but the error still exists...anymore suggestions please?

Comment: Run your commands inside the "dreamhouse-sfdx" folder.

Comment: I still think it's probably case-sensitivity. The command line and file ought to match. In fact, if you specify the directory with "-d force-app", you don't need to use "-p dreamhouse" which is another place that the cases don't match up i.e you could build the package version with just "sfdx force:package:version:create -d force-app -k test1234 --wait 10 -v DevHub"

Comment: Hey @aidan and lokes thanks for your help guys

Comment: Did it solve your problem in the end? If so, can you please mark the answer as correct?